# No Module named textblob

Tags: python, textblob

I installed text blob with the line below on my PC:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob.git
```

This then happened:

```
pcarrera@LAP-JYT456465 ~/Python
$ git clone https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob.git
Cloning into 'TextBlob'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 7, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 3729 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 3722
Receiving objects: 100% (3729/3729), 7.96 MiB | 10.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2054/2054), done.
```

I wanted to test it with the simple script below:

```
from textblob import textblob

text = ''' The movie was great. The movie was bad. The movie was really bad 
'''

blob = textblob(text)

for sentence in blob.sentences:
    print(sentence.sentiment.polarity)
```

But I got this error and I do not know how to move forward:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textblob_install.py", line 1, in <module>
    from textblob import textblob
ImportError: No module named textblob
```

Please help (new to Python)

Comment: You didn't actually install TextBlob, you only downloaded it. It is much easier to use `pip` or `conda` for installation than to install it from the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 4):

Use `python -m pip install textblob`. If you are using `conda` or `virtualenv`, you'll want to activate that environment before installing.

`git clone <blah>` will put files onto your computer, but your python interpreter doesn't know where those files are. The git repo probably has files like a `setup.py` among others, which can *help* you install it, but again it needs to still be installed in a useable way in the site-packages directory of your python installation.

Note, do *not* git clone into site-packages, it will throw errors like "TextBlob is not a python module"

Comment: you may also need to restart the kernal (in Jupyter Notebook)

Answer (score 1):

It is required to download and import library

```
!pip install textblob      #for installation

import textblob            #to import
from textblob import TextBlob
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue: `TextBlob`'s documentation seems to indicate that 2 steps are required to install textblob:

```
pip install -U textblob
```

and

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

After doing that, it worked for me. Documentation found at https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/

Comment: While executing the second command still getting the Error 
 "Error while finding module specification for 'textblob.download_corpora' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob')"

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package according to your python-version, in my case (Python3) I use the incorrect one, because the first time was:

```
!pip install textblob
```

And the correct instruction is:

```
!pip3 install textblob
```

Answer (score 0):

The installation of the package not completed. You should install the package properly.

```
pip install -U textblob
```

please refer the following link for more information
[readthedocs](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html)